# How I can convert an array value from LInkedHashMap to the List?

Tags: grails, groovy

I've got a simple LinkedHashMap `indexes`:

`[indexes: [909-720-15, EC5640001, BC2480001, BC2510001, BC2570001, EA0850002, EA0850003, EA1310005, EA1310006, EA1310008, EA1310009, EA1310010, EA1310011, EA1310012, EB7320001, EB7320002, EB7320003, EB7320004, EB7400001, EB7400002, ED93301, ED93302, ED93501]]`

How I can convert this map to the `List`?

If I use

```
List valueList = new ArrayList(indexes.values());
```

I receive a nested list: `[[909-720-15, EC5640001, BC2480001, BC2510001, BC2570001, EA0850002, EA0850003, EA1310005, EA1310006, EA1310008, EA1310009, EA1310010, EA1310011, EA1310012, EB7320001, EB7320002, EB7320003, EB7320004, EB7400001, EB7400002, ED93301, ED93302, ED93501]]`

I initialize my LinkedHashMap in a separate Groovy component:

```
def indexes = [indexes:indexes]
```

And pass it in a body of a POST call to the Java component

Comment: `List valueList = indexes.get("indexes");`

Comment: `List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>(indexes.get("indexes"));`

Comment: error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(Object)

Comment: What type is indexes.get("indexes")? Please give us a [reprex] so that we can tell the type of the LinkedHashMap's key/value pairs.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this map is created? I think the structure of this map is Map<String, Collection>

Comment: And don't use raw versions of generic types.  Properly parameterized types provide clarity for humans and enable the Java compiler to verify the type correctness of your code.  We would be able to answer from little more than you already presented if your types were properly parameterized.

Comment: @PauTrepat If the map had a Collection as its value type, the call `indexes.get("indexes")` would return a Collection, in which case the [ArrayList(Collection)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) constructor would've worked.

Comment: @Avi type of `indexes.get("indexes")` - `class java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: @Karen I'd suspect that you need to enforce a stricter type bound on your map, preferably Map<String,List<<String>>, Map<String,Collection<<String>> or something similar. However, if this is not possible, one thing that you can do is:
`List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>((TYPE<String>)indexes.get("indexes"));`, where TYPE = ArrayList or TYPE = Collection (literal text substitution).

Comment: `theMap.indexes` is enough in Groovy.  This already is a List.

Comment: The [java] tag that was once on this question has been removed.  Is that appropriate?  That is, the question *seemed* to be asking for Java code (for the Java component that receives the data), and removing the tag makes it seem like it is asking for Groovy.  So which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maps and Lists are fundamentally different data types, so there is no clear general mechanism for converting between the two.

Any way that preserves all the information present in the map would yield a list of `Map.Entry` objects or of some other representation of the (key, value) pairs in the map.  For example,

```
List<Map.Entry<KeyType, ValueType>> entryList = new ArrayList<?>(indexes.entrySet());
```

(Where `KeyType` and `ValueType` are placeholders for the actual types of your keys and values.  It's unclear what these are in your case, but maybe `String`.)

But as I understand it, you want instead the value associated with one specific key, expressed as a List.  In fact, you seem to have said that the value in question is *already* a List, in which case you do not necessarily need to "convert" the map to a list, as simply retrieving the wanted value from it may be sufficient:

```
List<ValueType> indexList = indexes.get("indexes");  // if indexes were properly paramterized
```

As I wrote in comments, you really ought not to work with raw versions of generic types, but if that's out of your control then you'll need to cast.  Supposing that the values in your map are lists of `String`s, as seems to be the case, this would be one reasonable approach:

```
List<String> indexList = (List<String>) indexes.get("indexes");
```

Note in particular that just because you receive the data in the form of a raw `Map` (if indeed you do) does not mean that you cannot transition to properly parameterized types, especially since you'll need to cast anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`Map` in java is `'key`' and `'value'` pair. So, you need to decide first if you want to convert all keys in `Map` to `List` or all values in `Map` to `List`. If you want to convert whole `Map` to `List` then it will `List` of `Map.Entry<K, V>`. See

```
    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("index1", "909-720-15");
    map.put("index2", "EC5640001");
    map.put("index3", "BC2480001");
    map.put("index4", "BC2510001");

    List<Map.Entry<String, String>> list = new ArrayList(map.entrySet());
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> l : list) {
        System.out.println("Key:-" + l.getKey() + " , Value:-" + l.getValue());
    }
```

If you want to convert values in `Map` to `List` then you need to do(for loop is just for example),

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList(map.values());
    for (String l : list) {
        System.out.println(l);
    }
```

Comment: I have a list as a Map "value" and want to assign it to a separate List

Comment: Updated my answer. If its still not clear then i think you need to clarify more on your question.